# Use the same hibernate 2nd level cache for multiple projects with infinispan?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, caching, infinispan

Is it possible to use the same hibernate 2nd level cache for multiple projects with infinispan?

Ex : I have 2 projects (A and B) which use the same entity (from a 3rd project), each projet has its own persistence.xml and acces to db.

Project A  create an entity and save it, he call Project B via remote proxy, in the same transaction.

Project B can't access to the entity created by Project A.

It's the same transaction, but different entity manager.

I enabled on the 2 persistence.xml the access to the 2nd lvl cache to infinispan but it doesn't work.

Can the 2nd level cache be used like this?

Thanks

Comment: How can it be the same transaction when you call it using remote proxy? Is that in the same JVM?
Before the transaction commits, the entity is not inserted into the cache, it's only cached locally in the session/entity manager. Therefore, you don't have access to that in the other entity manger. The same happens when you try to use two entity managers sequentially, without committing the tx (and without autocommit on in DB).

Comment: thanks Flavius for your  answer, it's the same JVM. i didn't realized that the cache was uptaded after the commit. So i guess there's no way to share the persistence context through 2 ears in the same JVM?